# Finding linear transformation for vector space of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Good evening everyone,

I understand how to find a determinant. What does it mean to have a linear transformation from the space $V$ of $2\times 2$ upper triangular matrices to $V$.

Also, how did they arrive to the solution? What are the questions should I ask myself when working with problems like this?

[image]
[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $T: V \to V$ be a linear transformation that transforms every $2\times 2$ upper triangular matrix $M$ to a new upper triangular matrix.

Firstly, we need to determine a basis of the vector space $$V = \{X: X \text{ is a $2\times 2$ upper triangular matrix}\}.$$

We can "easily" observe that a "standard" basis of $V$ is the set of matrices:
$$B = \left\{ \underbrace{\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}}_{E_1},\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1\\ 0& 0 \end{bmatrix}}_{E_2}, \underbrace{\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}}_{E_3}  \right\}.$$

All these matrices in $B$ are in $V$, they are linearly independent and they span $V$.

---

Now, we need to apply our transformation to every matrix in $B$ and express the transformed matrix in terms of $E_1, E_2, E_3$. 
Thus, we have:
$$T(E_1) = \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 3 \\ 0 & 4\end{bmatrix} \cdot E_1 = \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} = 2E_1 + 0E_2 + 0E_3$$

The above coefficients are going to form the first column of our transformation matrix $A$.

Following the same procedure for $E_2$ we have:
$$T(E_2) =\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 3\\ 0 & 4 \end{bmatrix} \cdot E_2 = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 2 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}= 0E_1 + 2E_2 + 0E_3.$$
The above coefficients are going to form the second column of our transformation matrix $A$.

Accordingly, we have $$T(E_3) = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 3\\ 0 & 4\end{bmatrix} = 0E_1+3E_2+4E_3.$$

Hence, we have:
$$A = \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 & 3 \\ 0 & 0 & 4\end{bmatrix}.$$

---

Practically, what does this transformation matrix $A$ mean?

Assume we have a row vector $[E_1 \quad E_2 \quad E_3]$. If we apply the transformation matrix to the previous vector i.e.
$$[E_1 \quad E_2 \quad E_3]\cdot \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 & 3\\ 0 & 0 & 4\end{bmatrix}=[2E_1 \quad 2E_2 \quad 3E_2 +4E_3]= [T(E_1)\quad T(E_2)\quad T(E_3)],$$
we get a row vector with the transformed matrices.

---

Addition to your comment:

As said before, the transformation is $T: V\to V$. We have the basis of $V: \beta =  (E_1, E_2, E_3).$

According to [this](https://math.colorado.edu/~nita/MatrixRepresentations.pdf), the **matrix representation of a linear transformation $T:V\to V$ in the ordered base $\beta$  is the $3\times 3$ matrix $A$ defined as**:
$$A = [T]_\beta = \Big[ [T(E_1)]_\beta\quad [T(E_2)]_\beta \quad [T(E_3)]_\beta\Big]$$

---

Now, we can treat the problem as following. Assume that we have the transformation $V\ni \begin{pmatrix} x & y \\ 0 & z\end{pmatrix} \mapsto \begin{pmatrix} x' & y' \\ 0 & z'\end{pmatrix}\in V.$  Essentialy, it's like transforming the vector $[x\quad y \quad z]$ into the vector $[x' \quad y' \quad z']$.

Thus, we can consider the transformation as
$$T(\mathbf{x}) = \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 2 & 3 \\ 0 & 0 & 4\end{bmatrix}\mathbf{x},$$
where $\mathbf{x} = [x \quad y \quad z]^T$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation :) In regards to the meaning of the matrix A, we were looking for the matrix that will transform any 2x2 matrix but we got 3x3 matrix. I understand that we can apply A on row vectors, but how row vectors are related to what was asked to do? Thank you. P.S. Is that one of those cases in Linear Algebra when it is too generalized and I shouldn't try to understand?

Comment: This problem unexpectedly came up on exam and I solved it :D Thanks again for the explanation again.

Comment: @Cooper Good for you and  you are welcome!